# Cannot access local server via Nautilus or Filezilla, but I can access it via Plex

Tags: networking, nautilus, ftp

I have an ubuntu 22.04 LTS server connected via ethernet to my wireless router, the device ip is 192.168.50.175, I can ping it from terminal and it shows up in the router map.
When I remote into Plex from a wireless laptop it gives both its private and public IDs and ports, but Nautilus and Filezilla cannot connect, either to public:port or private:port.

I am using ftp:// [ip:port]

Filezilla reports:
Status: Disconnected from server
Status: Connecting to [ip:port]...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Error:  Connection closed by server

Nautilus says, for both IPs: Unable to access location, Unexpected end of stream

I have read many entries in Ask Ubuntu and Filezilla Support but none of the answers that I understand have worked for me.

Can someone please point out what I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have a ftp server service set up and running on the Ubuntu server? The Plex and ftp are two different services.

Comment: Taking a hint, I have set it up and now I can get into the server using Terminal and Nautilus, but it drops me into my Home directory. Is there a way to get to root? (That's where lives the folder I want.) Inexplicably Filezilla still cannot access the server.

Comment: You can edit the ftp config file to change the "drop in directory". Alternately in Nautilus you can set up `ftp://ip_address:port/path/to/target/folder`.